# How to select the last record from MySQL table using SQL syntax if only a condition is meet

Tags: mysql

I have four fields in my db namely

```
Id(auto increment), 
dept_id, 
mat_code,
topic
```

I want to retrieve the last record in the database if a condition is meet. Am using dept_id  for the condition.

Comment: Last record based on what?

Comment: And you have tried to do this, How?

Comment: _the last record in the database if a condition is meet_ **What condition?**

Comment: The condition is using where clause. E.g where dept_Id = 1

Comment: Say there are 20 rows with dept_id = 1 then what? how will you describe the last row out these 20 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal method is to order the result in DESC order and LIMIT the result set to 1 row

```
SELECT Id, dept_id, mat_code, topic
WHERE dept_id = 'something'
ORDER BY Id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This returns the last row for a given department, which doesn't seem to be what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

What is the condition?  For what you want, I think a subquery is necessary:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM t
      ORDER BY Id DESC
      LIMIT 1
     ) t
WHERE dept_id = ??;
```

The subquery returns the last row (based on `id`).  The outer `WHERE` determines if conditions are true.