# my query is not displaying anything

Tags: php, mysql

Am using php, mysql to retrieve data from my database it is neither displaying error nor giving me the required data.

```
public function last_material_code($department_id){
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT material_code FROM materials_tbl WHERE dept_id = $department_id");
    return $query -> execute();
}

<?php
include_once ('select.class.php');

if(isset($_POST['department_id'])){
    $department_id = $_POST['department_id'];

    $object = new select_class($DB_con);
    $object -> last_material_code($department_id);
}
?>
```

Comment: public function last_material_code($department_id){
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT material_code FROM materials_tbl WHERE dept_id = $department_id");
return $query -> execute();
}

Comment: where/how are you "echoing" that?

Comment: Thats because you are not processing the resultset generated by your query. **Read the manual**

Comment: @RiggsFolly sort of; he's using a class/functions so maybe it's in there, who knows.

Comment: Its not in the method he shows i.e. `last_material_code()` @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yet another "FIIK" just like his last question http://stackoverflow.com/q/41430976/1415724 with an answer of yours in there. I'm out, *ciao!*

Comment: `->execute()` runs the query. Now you have to process the resultset generated by the query. **Read the manual**

Comment: Why is the function not inside the script tag? Where do you init DB_con? Also you are doing nothing with the result of the function call... This looks half-assed.

Comment: Sorry i did not upload all of my code, but if i call another function or method in that class it works very well, but for the last_material_code function it doesnt.

Comment: And for the love of good - don't **ever** place a value from the POST directly in your query! Google "SQL injection" for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i later did in my function, and it worked...

```
public function last_material_code($department_id){
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT  material_code FROM materials_tbl
    WHERE dept_id = $department_id ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $query -> execute();
    if ($query){
        while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){  
            echo $row["material_code"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should return the fetched result `$query->fetch()`